# „Du hast vielleicht Ideen“

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Du hast vielleicht Ideen, Balu

Was bedeutet hier [„vielleicht“](http://www.dict.cc/?s=vielleicht)? Es kann nicht „möglicherweise“ bedeuten, weil es deutlich ist, dass Balu gute Ideen hat.

([Quelle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCv0cRSdh68#t=02m07s))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Du hast vielleicht Ideen!

ist eine [stehende Wendung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stehende_Wendung) und ist ähnlich wie *"Wie stellst du dir das vor?"* oder *"Du hast nichts als Unsinn im Kopf"* zu verstehen.

Das Wort *vielleicht* hat hier nicht die Bedeutung von "möglicherweise", sondern **dient** [laut Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vielleicht_etwa_tatsaechlich)

> **als Partikel in Ausrufesätzen der emotionalen Nachdrücklichkeit und weist auf das hohe Maß hin, in dem der genannte Sachverhalt zutrifft**

Ein anderes Beispiel für die genannte Verwendung von *vielleicht*:

> Ich war vielleicht dumm, als ich den teuren Gebrauchtwagen gekauft habe!

Hier steht *vielleicht* wieder nicht für *möglicherweise*. Es ist klar, dass ich dumm war, und das *vielleicht* verstärkt die Aussage.

---

*Eine kleine Anmerkung:* Wenn man die Wortfolge im letzten Beispiel ändert und es nicht als Ausruf sieht, dann ändert sich der Sinn der Aussage und *vielleicht* erhält die Bedeutung von *möglicherweise*:

> Vielleicht war ich dumm, als ich den teuren Gebrauchtwagen gekauft habe.

Comment: Aha! Dein Beispiel hatte ich als _möglicherweise_ verstanden.

Comment: Dann hätte ich die Wortfolge ändern müssen: *"Vielleicht war ich dumm, ..."*

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde nicht unbedingt folgern, das es gute Ideen sind.

In folgenden Zusammenhang eher nicht

> Du hast vielleicht komische Ideen.
>
> Du hast vielleicht merkwürdige Ideen.

In folgendem Zusammenhang ohne Bewertung

> Du hast vielleicht ungewöhnliche Ideen
>
> Du hast vielleicht originelle Ideen

Und hier mit eindeutig positiver Bewertung

Du hast vielleicht eine großartige Idee

Du hast vielleicht eine famose Idee

Answer (score 0):

Es ist eher ein "Du kommst auf Ideen, da wäre ich nie drauf gekommen". "Möglicherweise" wäre hier meiner Meinung nach fehl am Platz.